# What is difference between bag vs idbag in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have two entites i.e.employee information and transfer information maintains upto till date.So In those sceniores which can i choose bag or idbag?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Hibernate collection performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-collections) to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

An idbag lets you add a surrogate generated column to your many2many table

You have to add the generator in your definition, and also make the other side of the many2many relationship the "inverse"